# Octave model matrix

Tags: matrix, model, octave

Is there a simple (non for loop) way to create a model matrix in Octave. In R i use model.matrix() to do this.

I have this array:

```
array = [1;2;3;2]
```

and i need (for regression reasons)

```
*(model = [1 0 0 0; 0 1 0 1; 0 0 1 0])* EDIT on my side
result is this model (colum 1 is for 1, column 2 for the two's etc.:
model = [1 0 0 ; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 1 ; 0 1 0]
```

I can do this with a for loop:

```
model = zeros(4,3);

for i=1:4
 model(i,array(i)) = 1; 
end
```

but it would be nice to do this in one step something like:

```
model = model.matrix(array)
```

i can than include it in a formula straight away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn your values into linear indices like so:

```
octave:1> array = [1 2 3 2];
octave:2> model = zeros ([numel(array) max(array)]);
octave:3> model(sub2ind (size (model), 1:numel(array), array)) = 1
model =

   1   0   0
   0   1   0
   0   0   1
   0   1   0
```

Because your matrix will be very sparse, a possible optimization is to create a sparse matrix instead.

```
octave:4> sp = sparse (1:numel(array), array, 1, numel (array), max (array))
sp =

Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 4, cols = 3, nnz = 4 [33%])

  (1, 1) ->  1
  (2, 2) ->  1
  (4, 2) ->  1
  (3, 3) ->  1

octave:5> full (sp)
ans =

   1   0   0
   0   1   0
   0   0   1
   0   1   0
```

This will take a lot less memory but many functions will be unable to handle them and convert them to a full matrix anyway. So whether this is worth is dependent on what you want to do next.

Comment: thanks, quite interesting. If i transpose and mirror "model"  i get what i need. But i still have a 2 step proces. I am hoping for some optimized code that does this all at once. I can write a function that has as input array and  outputs "model": function [model] = model.matrix(array) .... end. But optimized code works usualy much better and faster on huge matices.

Comment: @irJvV what do you mean optimized? This is already quite optimized and it returned the matrix you describe on your question. You don't have to transpose the model, you can just swap the arguments to `sub2ind()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I made a mistake in the result "model" -> the result should be model = [1 0 0 ; 0 1 0 ; 0 0 1 ; 0 1 0] (i will edit the question) but with a transopse on model from your function i will have that model' so perfect. With optimized code i mean that code that is part of the core Octave is usualy more fast and stable than similar code you write yourself and it works with a simple argument (model' works better than whatever code i write myself to do a transpose and its all in the one '. I like Octave a lot for cascaded functional prog with matrix calculations :)

Comment: you ment:  array = [1 2 3 2];
model = zeros ([numel(array) max(array)]);
model(sub2ind (size (model), 1:numel(array), array)) = 1 which works fine too without a transpose. I still need multiple lines of code though while i cascade this step in a larger function. My current solution is your code in function [model] = model.matrix(array) .... end. Thanks. If you put that in an answer i will accept it and everybody who is looking for something similar can use it too. :^)

Comment: @irJvV I have adjusted the answer to match your question. "With optimized code i mean that code that is part of the core Octave..." My answer makes use of builtin functions and indexing operations only. Your reasoning is incorrect in this case. Remember that a lot of Octave is written in Octave itself so code written by you can be just as fast, as long as you write it smart. The only optimization I can think of this, is to create a sparse matrix instead.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Could you give the example with a sparce matrix as well. I have used Sparce Matrices in Python a lot but i am not familiar with this in Octave. Would be very nice to get rid of all the 0's in the object / saved matrix. Perhaps you know a nice link with explanations too. :^)

Comment: @irJvV I have added an example to use a sparse matrix. The [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Sparse-Matrices.html) would be the place to read on the sparse matrices (and of course, the help text for `sparse()`).